# Уменьшение массива С#

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть массив myIntArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; мне из него надо сделать  myIntArray1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4};  но в моём случае выводит  { 0, 0, 0, 0} что и логично . Так как массиву не передаются числа а передаю только  размер массива равный 4. Что я делаю не так ?

```
 using System;

 public class Class1
{

static void Main()

{
        int[] myIntArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] myIntArray1 =  new int [myIntArray.Length -1 ] ;

        for (int i = 0; i < myIntArray1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myIntArray1[i]);

        }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] myIntArray1 = new int [myIntArray.Length - 1] ;
Array.Copy(myIntArray, 0, myIntArray1, 0, myIntArray1.Length);
```